# prepared statement sets column to null

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to set my code from escape strings to prepared statements. I'm getting an error message, that says Column 'name' cannot be null. The 'name' column should be coming from a post method. I'm not sure if using question marks is a good way, but that's what they write on different pages.

```
 <form action="inserttest.php" method="post">
```

my insert code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "reg");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


// Prepare an insert statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO cards (name, phone, phone2, email, zipcode, address, job, description, userid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssisssi", $name, $phone, $phone2, $email, $zipcode, $address, $job, $description, $userid);

    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['phone'])){
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['phone2'])){
        $phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['zipcode'])){
        $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['address'])){
        $address = $_POST['address'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['job'])){
        $job = $_POST['job'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['description'])){
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    }


    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not execute query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` to make sure it contains all of the keys/values you think it should have.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; }` - if it does not go into this if branch, because the POST parameter is not set - then you don’t set `$name` _anywhere_, yet you try to use it as a parameter to bind to your statement … All of those variables should be properly initialized with a default value, in case the POST parameter you otherwise want to get the value from, was not set in the first place.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What happens when one of the `$_POST` is not set? I don't see the reason of checking  them if there is no else statement. it will throw an error if one is not set

Comment: Thanks guys. Succesfully solved the problem.

Comment: To go along with CBroe's statement, You may not want to initialize the variables first, but instead return back to the form if the proper variables aren't passed through, depending on what you want to be required and what you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are going to check if POST parameter are set i.e.  `if(isset($_ ...` then provide an else statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $name = 'No name was provided';
}
```

If the name is important and must be provided: You can put it at the top of your query before you execute it, and exit the result if it is not provided

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    die('Name has to be provided to proceed');
}
```

Other checks: Check if your form has the name field and it is named correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't die like the in a live application. Instead, store the error to the session and return to the previous page.

Comment: If you are returning your result using ajax, you can die(). I have used die as an example since we don't know how he is running his HTML

Comment: Try. The OP shows `<form action="inserttest.php" method="post">`, but we don't know if there's an ajax intercepting the form submit.